# Steadily Increasing number of EJB @Singleton Weld Proxy Instances

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

We have an EJB @Singleton because we can benefit from:

- @DependsOn
- @Startup, @PostConstruct, etc...
- @LocalBean, inject resources like ManagedScheduledExecutorService
- @ConcurrencyManagement

The EJB Singleton is part of an EAR deployment. To be able to use it in legacy code not in scope of EJB or CDI, we currently inject it manually using something like `CDI.current().select(<type-of-singleton-EJB>).get()`.

Now we noticed that we have a steadily increasing number of `$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$`and `$$$viewxxx` instances of that singleton which I believe is due to the fact that for CDI, the EJB @Singleton is in the @Dependent pseudo scope so all those manually injected instances live as long as our legacy code class, which is probably just as long as the application lives.
Note it is just the number of proxy instances increasing, not the actual instance, which is only one.

There seem to be several solutions:

1. Annotate the @Singleton EJB also with @ApplicationScoped: this works, there is only one instance of the proxy and the view each
2. Replace the manual CDI select with a JNDI lookup: this also works, there is only one instance of the view
3. Use CDI.current.destroy() to remove the proxy instance: have not tried because it doesn't look trivial to implement in our scenario
4. Turn the legacy code into EJB or CDI managed beans as well and do a regular @Inject: @ApplicationScoped might be needed on the @Singleton EJB anyway?

So my question(s): is the observation correct at all, is it okay to annotate a bean with both EJB @Singleton and CDI @ApplicationScoped and which solution is preferred?

Comment: It is definitely allowed to annotate a `@Singleton` as an `@ApplicationScoped` bean so that CDI can put the proxy of the bean in `application-scope`. All ejb beans per specs are in dependent scope, and the only bean you can put in applicationscope is `@Singleton` anyway. But then, why not just use `@EJB` to inject the ejb bean inside a CDI bean?

Comment: The only time i add the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation to a `@Singleton` ejb bean, is if i expect to use `Instance<Type>` injection

Comment: Your comments pretty much answer my question - if you turn them into an answer I'll happily accept it. To your question - I can't use @EJB in those legacy classes because they are neither under EJB nor CDI control so I can only use `CDI.current().select(...).get()` or a JNDI lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, EJB `@Singleton` is *not necessarily* translated into `@Dependent` bean in CDI. It is just Weld's default behaviour if no other CDI scope is added.
Here is a list of how EJB 'maps' to CDI scopes:

- `@Stateless` -> `@Dependent`
- `@Stateful` -> `@SessionScoped`
- `@Singleton` -> `@Dependent` *or* `@ApplicationScoped`
- In Weld:

  - `@Singleton` -> `@Dependent` (just the proxy is created on every injection, otherwise it obviously delegates to the same underlying EJB singleton)
  - `@Singleton` + `@ApplicationScoped` -> `@ApplicationScoped`

And here is a [link to spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#session_beans) describing it.

> To be able to use it in legacy code not in scope of EJB or CDI, we currently inject it manually using something like `CDI.current().select(...).get()`.

If I get it correctly, you retrieve this EJB singleton from various places in your app using `CDI.current()`. Now, this can be tricky as `CDI.current()` is poorly defined and tries to "guess" what bean manager to use in order to retrieve the bean. If we are talking EAR deployments, this gets even trickier. Ideally you would want to avoid `CDI.current()` if possible.

> Now we noticed that we have a steadily increasing number of $Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$and $$$viewxxx instances of that singleton which I believe ...

In your case there is only `@Singleton` annotation so the proxy CDI behaves like `@Dependent` scope. Hence new one for each injection (done by `CDI.current()` in your case). But you are injecting into non contextual object (not into a bean to simplify it) hence you would also need to take care of the bean and dispose of it once you no longer need it.

> ...is it okay to annotate a bean with both EJB @Singleton and CDI @ApplicationScoped

As you by now understood it is not just okay, is it what you oftentimes do, as the mapping between `@Singleton` and `ApplicationScoped` looks way more natural then with `@Dependent`. **I would say this is a go-to solution for your problem.**

> ...so all those manually injected instances live as long as our legacy code class, which is probably just as long as the application lives.

Well, if you execute that code repeatedly and you re-inject it on every run, then there is your problem. Since the legacy code is not a CDI bean (according to what you say it is a non-contextual instance), this will have to create a new proxy it hands over every time. You would need to handle dependent bean disposal as well - something along the lines of your third proposed solution.

Comment: P.S. I am fine adjusting the answer assuming you provide more information. As it stands I have to guess a lot of things.

Comment: I've updated my question regarding deployment structure, how we are retrieving the EJB instance and the number of proxy instances. We re-inject on every run but when adding `@ApplicationScope` there is only one proxy instance, so explicitly annotating with `@ApplicationScope` seems to cause different behaviour than the mapping you describe alone.

Comment: In our CDI-Unit tests the behaviour also changes by explicitly annotating with `@ApplicationScope` so I wonder if `@Singleton` is really effectively mapped to `@ApplicationScope`, maybe there is a bug in Weld?

Comment: Spec allows for both (quoting from the link in answer) - `A singleton session bean must belong to either the @ApplicationScoped scope or to the @Dependent pseudo-scope.`

Comment: So Weld is compliant but you were right, I did make a mistake here. Without any *CDI* annotation, the `@Singleton` will be `@Dependent` (**the proxy only! It still points to the same EJB singleton**) hence you would need to destroy those proxies. But you can also add `@ApplicationScoped` and it will then behave just as you described which is desired behaviour for you I think. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Alright, edited. Sorry for the fuss, those mappings between EJB and CDI are not always clear and I jumble them from time to time.

Comment: Great! Should you not also edit "EJB `@Singleton` is not translated into `@Dependent` bean in CDI"?

Comment: Yep, I should. Done.